# Custom Segue - unrecognized selector sent to instance - setUseDefaultModalPresentationStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7, segue

I'm using this [custom segue](https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFBlurSegue). It works perfectly on iOS8+, however, on iOS 7, I get this error.

```
2015-10-09 13:59:02.891 APPNAME[1790:60b] -[APPNAME.AFBlurSegue setUseDefaultModalPresentationStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ddafe0
2015-10-09 13:59:02.901 APPNAME[1790:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[APPNAME.AFBlurSegue setUseDefaultModalPresentationStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ddafe0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e5c6f83 0x38d77ccf 0x2e5ca917 0x2e5c9203 0x2e518768 0x312c0381 0x312b63fb 0x30e19037 0x30e18fd7 0x30e18fb1 0x30e04717 0x30e18a2f 0x30e18701 0x30e136cb 0x30de88cd 0x30de6f77 0x2e59220b 0x2e5916db 0x2e58fecf 0x2e4faebf 0x2e4faca3 0x33400663 0x30e4714d 0x13e65c 0x39284ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The problem is, the crash is vague. I even tried putting breakpoints everywhere and tried to catch any errors thrown. However, it still doesn't point to where the error could be.

The fact that it seems like an argument/selector error, I suspect this might be a Swift 2 error. The only place I can find a reference to setUseDefaultModalPresentationStyle is [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate.h).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try overriding that method in `AFBlurSegue` and putting a breakpoint in it so you can see the stack trace where it is getting called.  Might help figure out what is happening.

Comment: I've tried this, I've even went as far as to re-write "AFBlurSegue.m" in Swift, line for line. Still not able to see the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try set Segue setting to Custom on the segue in storyboard, and set the style programmatically:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    destination.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because this library uses the `UIVisualEffectView` to get the blur effect. Unfortunately `UIVisualEffectView` is only available in **iOS 8 and up**.

See the **[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/)** for more information.

Unfortunately, if you want to use your fancy blur transitions, your app wont be compatible with iOS 7 and below, which isn't that much of a problem, since currently only 10% devices have iOS below iOS 8.

**[More info here](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/)**

### Solution:

You could solve this using an older version of this library which does not yet use the `UIVisualEffectView` but instead uses `UIImage+ImageEffects.m` to get the blur effect.

Comment: If you look into the library, there is a check for if it is iOS7 or later. It only uses UIVisualEffectView in the later portion, for iOS7, it uses a normal UIImageView and UIImage+ImageEffects.m for the blur.

Comment: Actually, looking at the code the check it has in there is for iOS version <= 7.1 which obviously doesn't work on 7.2 or later.  Try changing it to check for iOS version <= 8.0 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I didn't notice that. However, since I did write a port of this in Swift, I had already done this check and it still fails. You can see the port here: https://gist.github.com/jathu/9aa35c2f4d7fb32159ff